# Resolve mongodb installation error on ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I'm installing Mongodb on ubuntu  but it is not installing, It has some dpkg error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Keli.png)

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: Did you follow this instruction: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use sed:

```
sudo sed -i '/mongodb/d' /var/lib/dpkg/statoverride
```

and try to install again